# Should there be a list of canonical questions on Project Management?

Tags: discussion, answers, faq-proposed, canonical

Yes, we do have PMBOK, but this forum is slowly generating its own body of knowledge. Think PM.SE could take a page from Server Fault's [book](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) and mark certain accepted Q/A pairs as canonical and list them on meta and provide link there from the FAQ. Right now I'm thinking, for instance, about Q/As on change management, or things like [micro-management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-to-avoid-micro-managing-a-software-development-team) or [estimation of man-hours](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25/how-to-estimate-amount-of-work-man-hours-for-an-unfamiliar-task).

Comment: What do you see as the benefit?  What problem do you think this would solve?

Comment: @jmort253 : The main benefit of having a small subset of questions marked as _canonical_ is reduction in time spent on learning the scope and achievements of PM.SE for those who want to learn. While writing up candidate questions, meta posters/readers will be spotting gaps in coverage, thus provoking new questions. It takes quite a while to navigate the question collection and mark favorites, separating the wheat from the chaff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing I can think of that would make this a bad idea, and aside from that, experimentation with new ideas is a good thing. My suggestion is to start doing this, but start small so you can get feedback from others.

This will tell you more about whether or not this is worth doing and also help get others involved. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, will start a new meta item to collect/discuss proposed canonicals.

Comment: @DeerHunter - That's awesome. In addition, feel free to use our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management) for extended discussions and collaboration with others on these ideas.